What is the meaning of *((_DWORD *)
I disassemble some code using IDA Pro and get the pseudo-code. It showed something like below.
*((_DWORD *)a1 + 150) = 3;
*(_DWORD *)(a1 + 604) = 1;
I can't understand what is happening for this two code, anybody can explain？

This is pretty much standard C representation
*((_DWORD *)a1 + 150) = 3; means a1 is a pointer to _DWORD and we dereference the 150th member of the array with base a1
Note that *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 604) = 1; the order of brackets is a bit different and assuming the type of a1 - I guess its dereferencing the 151st element since sizeof(_DWORD) is 4 and 604 = 151 x 4.
You can pretty much recreate this
void f(int * a) {
    a[150] = 3;
    a[151] = 1;
}

int main() {
    int x[256];
    f(x);
}

compile this - alternatively gcc.godbolt here
$ gcc -O1 -o test test.c

loading this in ida and decompiling
void __fastcall f(__int64 a1)
{
  *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 600) = 3;
  *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 604) = 1;
}

You can press Y after clicking on a1 and change the type of a1 to int * and get this
void __fastcall f(int *a1)
{
  a1[150] = 3;
  a1[151] = 1;
}

Note that this is not always true - a1 could be a pointer to a struct and the code could be changing a member.
